# top 'xterm': unknown terminal type

Tags: linux, shell, command, redhat, terminfo

I have an error when run TOP command:

```
>top
'xterm': unknown terminal type.

> echo $TERM
xterm

> echo $DISPLAY
DYSPLAY: Undefined variable.

> cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)

> ls /usr/share/terminfo/
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a A b c d e E f g h i j k l L m M n N o p P q Q r s t u v w x X z


> ls /usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm
/usr/share/terminfo/x/xterm
```

i have that problem also with Root.

does TOP use xterm?

How can i do?

Comment: i'm using ssh via putty.exe

Comment: D**Y**SPLAY: Undefined variable ?!?

Comment: DYSPLAY? you have a typo somewhere in .profile or like

Answer (score 16):

try adding

```
export TERM=linux
```

at the end of your .bashrc files (/home/myuser/.bashrc, /root/.bashrc).  The problem is that the terminal definition 'xterm' is undefined

Comment: export TERM=linux ->
top ->
'linux': unknown terminal type.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another possible cause of `top` terminal problems.

I had the same problem (on one particular SLES 11.3 box) - whatever I set `TERM` to (default was `xterm`), top would say "`unknown terminal type`".
My `/usr/share/terminfo` files were all fine, as was `/etc/termcap`, and my ncurses library.

Then I noticed that top ran fine as another user, so it must be an environment problem.
I tracked it down to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, which was set to
    `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/pgAdmin3/lib:/opt/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib:`
(I have PostgreSQL installed on this box).

The problem was that PostgreSQL supplies its own `libncurses.so.5` library (among many others), and `top` doesn't work with it.

If I unset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, or make PostgreSQL's library a soft link to `/usr/lib/libncurses.so`, then `top` works fine again.

Comment: This was my exact problem. I ended up moving the LD_LIBRARY_PATH setup to a wrapper shell script instead of on the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

Instead of top, can you please try with below arguments

top -n 2 -b

it worked for me