# Failing cronjob: 'unknown': unknown terminal type

Tags: linux, cron, debian

I have this **cronjob**: (it's a single line, I formatted it only here for better readability)

```
* 5-7 * * * ( 
   sudo pstree -pa > "$HOME/log/`date "+\%F-\%T"`-pstree.txt";
   sudo top -o \%MEM | head -25 > "$HOME/log/`date "+\%F-\%T"`-topMEM.txt";
   sudo top -o \%CPU | head -25 > "$HOME/log/`date "+\%F-\%T"`-topCPU.txt"
)
```

The **first command runs successfully**, the file is created with pstree inside it.

But the **second and third commands fail** and result in empty files.

The only info in the the mail is:

```
'unknown': unknown terminal type.
```

I'm just starting out with Debian, etc, so sorry for the newbie question, any advice is welcome! :)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24676687/top-xterm-unknown-terminal-type/28290724) answer your question?

Comment: `top` is intended for interactive use on a terminal. When run from `cron`, its `stdout` is not connected to a terminal. Maybe `top`'s `-b` (Batch-mode) and `-n` (Number-of-iterations) options would help. see [man top](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)

Comment: use `top` with `b` if you want to send result to a file. Else top will update screen (and so it need a terminal, and so you cannot redirect the result).

Comment: Thanks, adding the b flag solved it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

top's `-b` (Batch-mode) and `-n` (Number-of-iterations) options helped.

By default top is interactive so I have fetch a static result to save it into a file.

Example: `top -b -n1`